# How to use OmniXML parser in THTTPRIO for my SOAP client

Tags: delphi, soap, omnixml, delphi-xe7

I read on Embarcadero's "What's New in Delphi and C++Builder XE7" page [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What's_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE7) about SOAP support with OmniXML.

> **New Cross-Platform XML Vendor that Improves Performance**
>
> In addition to MSXML and ADOM, RAD Studio now provides a new XML
>   vendor: OmniXML. The OmniXML cross-platform XML vendor shows much
>   better performance results than the alternative cross-platform XML
>   vendor: ADOM. The OmniXML XML vendor in RAD Studio is based on
>   OmniXML, but it includes additional features, such as namespace
>   support, and it is compatible with SOAP.

The bits about "**performance improvement**" and "**compatible with SOAP**" made me download the XE7 demo to give it a shot. However the only reference I can find of OmniXML is in the `TXMLDocument.DomVendor` property where I can set the value to "Omni XML".

Can anyone enlighten me how to use the OmniXML parser in my SOAP client? (I am assuming that it's the THTTPRIO component that needs modification.)

Answer (score 2):

```
var rio: THTTPRIO;

rio.WSDLItems.DOMVendor := GetDOMVendor(sOmniXmlVendor);
```

(Untested, I got that by browsing the sources.)

Comment: Thanks gabr, I'll check it out! TTYL